# Unable to start OpenVpn on FreeBsd 11, it asks for --dev which I've already specified

Tags: vpn, openvpn, freebsd

My  /etc/rc.conf in FreeBsd 11:

```
  hostname="abcd"
  sshd_enable="YES"
  static_routes="linklocal"
  ifconfig_vtnet0="DHCP"
  ifconfig_vtnet0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
  ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
  rtsold_enable="YES"
  rtsold_flags="-aF"

  nginx_enable="YES"
  postgresql_enable="YES"

  openvpn_enable="YES"
  openvpn_configfile="/usr/local/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf" # it exists
  openvpn_if="tun"
  gateway_enable="YES"
  firewall_enable="YES"
  firewall_type="open"

  firewall_nat_enable="YES"
  firewall_nat_interface="vtnet0"

  natd_enable="YES"
  natd_interface="vtnet0"
  natd_flags="-dynamic -m"
```

When trying to start openvpn:

```
$ sudo openvpn --config  openvpn.conf 
WARNING: Ignoring option 'dh' in tls-client mode, please only include this in your server configuration
disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Options error: You must define TUN/TAP device (--dev)
```

But why? I've already specified a device in rc.conf

How to fix that?

p.s.

`sudo service openvpn start` ===> `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/openvpn: WARNING: failed to start openvpn`

Answer (score 0):

`rc.conf` settings are used by startup scripts in `/etc/rc.d` and `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`. `openvpn` itself doesn't read this file. You need to use a script from `rc.d` to start `openvpn`.

Comment: sudo service openvpn start ===> `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/openvpn: WARNING: failed to start openvpn`

Comment: @lvanari you need to look into appropriate logs for the cause of failure to start `openvpn`.